# Error when Make CLucene

Tags: cmake, clucene

I'm using a MBP OSX(10.9) and is new to CLucene and I'm having problem installing it. Despite following the installation guide closely, I still hit these errors while making the file

```
[  0%] Building CXX object src/shared/CMakeFiles/clucene-shared.dir/CLucene/SharedHeader.o
In file included from /Users/youhock/Downloads/clucene-core-2.3.3.4/src/shared/CLucene/SharedHeader.cpp:8:
In file included from /Users/youhock/Downloads/clucene-core-2.3.3.4/src/shared/CLucene/_SharedHeader.h:13:
In file included from /Users/youhock/Downloads/clucene-core-2.3.3.4/src/shared/CLucene/SharedHeader.h:201:
In file included from /Users/youhock/Downloads/clucene-core-2.3.3.4/src/core/CLucene/debug/lucenebase.h:10:
/Users/youhock/Downloads/clucene-core-2.3.3.4/src/shared/CLucene/LuceneThreads.h:56:19: error: 
      unknown type name 'pthread_t'
                static _LUCENE_THREADID_TYPE _GetCurrentThreadId();
                       ^
/Users/youhock/Downloads/clucene-core-2.3.3.4/src/shared/CLucene/LuceneThreads.h:40:41: note: 
      expanded from macro '_LUCENE_THREADID_TYPE'
          #define _LUCENE_THREADID_TYPE pthread_t
                                        ^
/Users/youhock/Downloads/clucene-core-2.3.3.4/src/shared/CLucene/LuceneThreads.h:57:18: error: 
      unknown type name 'pthread_t'
                        static _LUCENE_THREADID_TYPE CreateThread(lucene...
                               ^
/Users/youhock/Downloads/clucene-core-2.3.3.4/src/shared/CLucene/LuceneThreads.h:40:41: note: 
      expanded from macro '_LUCENE_THREADID_TYPE'
          #define _LUCENE_THREADID_TYPE pthread_t
                                        ^
/Users/youhock/Downloads/clucene-core-2.3.3.4/src/shared/CLucene/LuceneThreads.h:58:34: error: 
      unknown type name 'pthread_t'
                        static void JoinThread(_LUCENE_THREADID_TYPE id);
                                               ^
/Users/youhock/Downloads/clucene-core-2.3.3.4/src/shared/CLucene/LuceneThreads.h:40:41: note: 
      expanded from macro '_LUCENE_THREADID_TYPE'
          #define _LUCENE_THREADID_TYPE pthread_t
                                        ^
3 errors generated.
make[2]: *** [src/shared/CMakeFiles/clucene-shared.dir/CLucene/SharedHeader.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [src/shared/CMakeFiles/clucene-shared.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Appreciate if anyone could help me with this? Thanks in advance

Comment: Likely this is not a problem with CMake build but rather with CLucene itself. For some reasons `pthread_t` (which is the basic type for "posix threads" identifier) wasn't defined. Most probably this is because header file <pthread.h> wasn't included in CLucene sources. So you may grep for `#include <pthread.h>` and check if such inclusion exists and it's not hidden under some `#ifdef`s

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28175358/2397318).

Bascially you have to patch

- src/shared/CLucene/LuceneThreads.h
- src/shared/CLucene/config/repl_tchar.h

The other post contains the links as well.